# Mustash Cache breaking rules

Tags: stash, database-error, mustash

When I try saving Cache breaking rules with Mustash, I get this error:

```
Error Number: 1366

Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'group_id' at row 1

INSERT INTO `exp_stash_rules` (`plugin`, `hook`, `group_id`, `bundle_id`, `scope`, `pattern`, `ord`, `site_id`) VALUES ('channel_entries', '@all', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '', 0, '2')

Filename: third_party/mustash/models/mustash_model.php

Line Number: 574
```

Any thoughts on this?

We're using a Multi-Site Manager setup.

Comment: I am still having this issue. Anyone can help me out? I am just trying to add cache breaking rules without selecting a group (leaving it at '--', because I don't want to specify for every Channel entry once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer gave a solution here: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/mustash/viewthread/15161

Change the following code on line line 664 in mcp.mustash.php:

```
'group_id' => $group[$index],
```

To:

```
'group_id' => ($group[$index] == "NULL" ? NULL : $group[$index]),
```

Comment: Alright. I did the same for bundle_id and scope. Danger there? Any reason why this is not possible out of the box?